# Real time log viewer for intellij IDE

Tags: logging, plugins, intellij-idea, viewer, jetbrains-ide

Given a master log file updated across a network, what is the best way to display that in the intellij IDE? Is it possible to develop a plugin that would add a log tab (similar to the default event log at the bottom of the IDE) inside the IDE to display this data? Or are there any inbuilt features in intellij that I could use to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated on how to approach this issue.

The log should display real time updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been working on this for a few days, and it is possible to accomplish this through an intellij plugin. Specifically a Tool Window. More information on tool window plugin development for intellij can be found here.
[Intellij Tool Window plugin development](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/user_interface_components/tool_windows.html#how-to-create-a-tool-window)

The newly added Tool Window UI can be customized further using Swing components.